# array push returns true or false instead of the objects pushed

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of products with different properties, including Product quantity. I need to push products where product quantity are less than 5 in a new array.

I have used filter and push functions in order to push the required elements in the new array.

products = array with the elements
lowStockProucts = new array

```
var lowStockProducts = [];

products
    .filter((el)=>{
        lowStockProducts.push(el.productQuantity < 5);
        return lowStockProducts
})

console.log(lowStockProducts);
```

Expected the new array to contain the objects with productQuantity less than five, instead, the output is "[ true, false, true, false, false ]".

The order is correct the first and third elements quantities are indeed less than 5 but this is not the expected output.

Comment: The filter isn't doing anything here; you don't assign the return value, you could just replace it with forEach. If you actually want to filter, the callback needs to return the boolean, and you shouldn't be pushing to another array yourself.

Comment: What value do you `push`? This: `el.productQuantity < 5`. What value is that? The result of the `<` operator, which is a boolean. And you're pushing that unconditionally, meaning without any `if`, meaning you're not only pushing values under 5.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, you are right, I got confused with the use of push and filter. Instead of pushing the values in the new array, all I needed to do was assign the return value to the new array as you mention. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You push the value of the condition, but you need to take the result of the filtering by respecting the check.

```
var lowStockProducts = products.filter(el => el.productQuantity < 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

`.push(el.productQuantity < 5)` will push a boolean. You need to `return` the boolean instead, for the `.filter` test to work properly:

```
const lowStockProducts = products.filter(el => el.productQuantity < 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns following-

> A new array with the elements that pass the test. If no elements pass
>   the test, an empty array will be returned.

You don't need a new separate array to store the result.I have demonstrated ,what you are expecting to do.

```js
lowStockProucts = new Array()
let products = [{
  "productQuantity": 2,
  "name": "A"
}, {
  "productQuantity": 21,
  "name": "Ac"
}]



var lowStockProducts = products
  .filter((el) => {

    return el.productQuantity < 5 // use condition like this
  })


console.log(lowStockProducts);
```